# Swift objc_sync_enter/exit Linux alternatives

Tags: linux, swift

For multithread concurency editing objects in `Swift` I use:

```
import Foundation
func lockForEdit(object: NSObject, closure: () -> Void) {
    objc_sync_enter(object)
    closure()
    objc_sync_exit(object)
}

// In each thread
lockForEdit (object: threadsDictionarie as NSObject) {
    threadsDictionarie.append(dict)
}
```

But in `Linux Ubuntu 14.04` with `Swift 3.0.1` I get:

use of unresolver identifier 'objc_sync_enter', 
use of unresolver identifier 'objc_sync_exit'

What to use for `Swift` in Linux for concurency editing objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no per-object locking in Swift. You could use `NSLock` or pthread locks as a replacement, but you need to maintain the lock/object mapping on your own.

Also, you may want to use a serial `DispatchQueue` instead of a lock in the first place (checkout: [About Dispatch Queues](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html)). But this obviously depends on what you are doing.

A way to do this is to add something like a `ThreadsafeDictionary` and wrap the real dictionary inside it. Like so:

```
class ThreadsafeDictionary<T> : ... all the protocols... {
  let lock = NSLock()
  var values = Dictionary<T>()
  ... all the methods you need ...
}
```

Presumably you can find an implementation of this on GitHub.

Comment: Of course it does, I use GCD on Linux all the time and just tried NSLock prior sending the answer (Trusty w/ Swift 3.0.1). Use Swift 3.0.x, that comes with GCD included. For older versions you need to compile GCD separatedly.

Comment: For using GCD it is necessary to use: import Dispatch